# VBA Excel Data Validation of

Tags: string, vba, validation, excel

I was looking for some help on creating a sub which does data validation on the values in column C in a worksheet 'Compare' based on possible values listed in a different worksheet 'mapping' in columns C, D, E etc. I wanted to have the possible values use string/pattern characters like # ? * to make the data validation more flexible. There could be anywhere from 1 to 5+ different possible values which varies by key.  Validation differences would be spit into an empty column D in worksheet Compare.

An Example with Data is likely most helpful here.

```
Static sheet 'mapping' . Key is Column A. Possible values in Columns C onwards
A               B               C               D               E               F               G
v1              CDID            ####            ###?            0
c52             FHAID           ER#             EP#             INVA            Z*              
c48             PLID            *
v24             CUSTID          ###             ###Q            ###P
c22             MATID           ???#            ??#             ?#
q23             LKKID           *


Input original sheet 'Compare'. Key is Column B. Column C contains Data to validate
A               B               C               D
c22             MATID           RT3FG
v24             CUSTID          456P
v1              CDID            5   
q23             LKKID           PORTA

Output sheet 'Compare'. Invalid values noted in Column D.
    A               B               C               D
c22             MATID           RT3FG           Error: Invalid value
v24             CUSTID          456P
v1              CDID            5               Error: Invalid Value    
q23             LKKID           PORTA
```

Any ideas on how to make this work? Compare worksheet will have all data starting in A1 with no headers. mapping sheet will be quite large with 100+ rows and probably requires a vlookup or similar to find correct row.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best (most efficient) way but I'd implement it like this: (1.) AlphaSort 'Mapping' on B, C, D (2.) AlphaSort 'Compare' on col B (for duplicates). (3.) Make function GetPatterns(ByVal strFromCompareColB As String) As String() - returns the array of all possible patterns. (4.) Move CompareColC to memArray. (5.) For Each itemX in memArray and For Each itemZ in patternArray RegEx.Pattern = patternArray(i), then if Not RegEx.Test(itemX) Then resultMemArray() = "Invalid Value", Next itemZ (pattern) , Next itemX (memArray). At the end (6,) CompareColD = resultMemArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming * is anything # is a number and ? is a char I came up with this

```
Sub CompareToMapping()
   Dim mapSheet As Worksheet: Set mapSheet = Sheets("Mapping")
   Dim compSheet As Worksheet: Set compSheet = Sheets("Compare")
   Dim mcell As Range
   Dim ccell As Range
   Dim rcell As Range

   'Loop throw all the rows in the compare sheet
   For Each ccell In compSheet.Range("a1", compSheet.Range("a" & compSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      'loop through and find a matching row from Mapping sheet
      For Each mcell In mapSheet.Range("a1", mapSheet.Range("a" & mapSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         If mcell = ccell And mcell.Offset(0, 1) = ccell.Offset(0, 1) Then
            'loop through valid format strings
            For Each rcell In mapSheet.Range(mcell, mapSheet.Cells(mcell.Row, mapSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
               ccell.Offset(0, 3) = "Error: Invalid value"
               If FormatCorrect(ccell.Offset(0, 2).Text, rcell.Offset(0, 2).Text) Then
                  'show error in column d
                  ccell.Offset(0, 3) = ""
                  Exit For
               End If
            Next rcell
            Exit For
         End If
      Next mcell
   Next ccell
End Sub

Function FormatCorrect(inString As String, inFormat As String) As Boolean
   Dim i As Integer: i = 0
   Dim curS, curF As String
   FormatCorrect = True

   ' first check for *
   If inFormat = "*" Then
      FormatCorrect = True
   ' next check if strings are the same length
   ElseIf Len(inString) <> Len(inFormat) Then
      FormatCorrect = False
   Else
      'compare 1 character at a time
      For i = 1 To Len(inString)
         curS = Mid(inString, i, 1)
         curF = Mid(inFormat, i, 1)
         If curF = "?" Then ' needs to be a letter
            If IsNumeric(curS) Then
               FormatCorrect = False
               Exit For
            End If
         ElseIf curF = "#" Then ' needs to be a number
            If Not IsNumeric(curS) Then
               FormatCorrect = False
               Exit For
            End If
         Else ' needs to be an exact match
            If curF <> curS Then
               FormatCorrect = False
               Exit For
            End If
         End If
      Next i
   End If
End Function
```

Tested and worked for me. Good luck :)